# SPSS/Python - Accessing variable labels

Tags: python, for-loop, key, spss

I am trying to access variable labels in for loop in SPSS using Python. The for loop iterates over a range of variables, deleting 1-3 and renaming 4 and 5 in a sequence of 5 variables. This works fine, but now when trying to access the variable labels via SPSS I am running into the 'unicode object has no attribute keyes' error.

I recognize that I need to somehow refer to the key instead of the string in my array, but as a novice programmer I am struggling to figure out how to update my existing code:

```
begin program.
import spss, spssaux
vdict=spssaux.VariableDict()
mylist=vdict.range(start="M10", end="ENDOK_D")
nvars = len(mylist)
mycounter = 1
durations = ""

for i in range(nvars):
  myvar = mylist[i]
  if (mycounter < 4): 
    spss.Submit("delete variables %s." % myvar)
    mycounter +=1
  elif (mycounter == 4): 
    varlabel = mylist[i].VariableLabel 
    spss.Submit('variable labels %s "%s" [TimeStamp]' % (myvar,varlabel) + ".")
    if (myvar.endswith("_C")): mynewvar = myvar[:-2] + "_TS"
    spss.Submit("rename variables (%s = %s)" % (myvar,mynewvar) + ".")
    spss.Submit("formats %s (DATETIME28.4)" % (mynewvar) + ".")
    mycounter +=1
  elif (mycounter == 5): 
    varlabel = mylist[i].VariableLabel 
    spss.Submit('variable labels %s "%s" [TimeStamp]' % (myvar,varlabel) + ".")
    if (myvar.endswith("_D")): mynewvar = myvar[:-2] + "_TSD"
    spss.Submit("rename variables (%s = %s)" % (myvar,mynewvar) + ".")
    durations += mynewvar + " "
    mycounter = 1
spss.Submit("alter type %s (F4.0)" % durations + ".")
end program.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The line 
`spss.Submit('variable labels %s "%s" [TimeStamp]' % (myvar,varlabel) + ".")` is what's causing you trouble.

The [TimeStamp] bit is basically telling python to look for a key named "TimeStamp" in a dictionary but before the [TimeStamp] it doesn't find the right data structure - namely a dictionary - but a string which does not have keys. Maybe this might make it clearer:

```
myDict = {
          "varname": "myVariable", 
          "label": "This is myVariable's label!", 
          "TimeStamp": "20190204-0814"
          }

print (myDict["varname"])
print (myDict["TimeStamp"])

>>> myVariable
>>> 20190204-0814
```

Python is looking for a data structure like this and wants to look up the key "TimeStamp". Now, I assume you just want your labels to read "Whatever Variable Label was assigned [TimeStamp]"?

Simply change the two lines to

```
spss.Submit('variable labels %s "%s" + " [TimeStamp]"' % (myvar,varlabel) + ".")
```